# jQuery Change Event Handler on List

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want an event handler triggered every time there is a change on a list (move item, add item, etc.) using jQuery.

The `.change()` handler doesn't seem to work as seen below:

http://jsfiddle.net/89wkL2s1/

```
$("#sortable").change(function(){
    alert("Change handler works");
});
```

How then can I catch all changes on the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for various events and then use

```
$('#sortable').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm too new to this to understand, but do you know of an example of this? I don't quite understand how to use .trigger

Comment: It really depends on how you want to use it. It might be easier to use Alexander's answer for your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can attach **sotrable** event like this :

```
$("#sortable").on("sort", function(){
    console.log("sort handler works");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89wkL2s1/1/)

check the [sortable api here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) , they have nice examples of everything .

Answer (score 0):

The `update` event is triggered each time the list is re-sorted:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#sortable").sortable({
         'update' : function (event, ui) {
             console.log("The list's been rearranged.");
         }
     });
     $("#sortable").disableSelection();
 });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/89wkL2s1/2/).

References:

- [`sortable()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/).

  - [`update`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update).